# What is the equivalent of UpdateWindow() in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am new to wxWidgets and trying to find out how to force the painting of a window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [wxWindow::Refresh](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxwindow.html#wxwindowrefresh) or [wxWindow::Update](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxwindow.html#wxwindowupdate)